# How to Interpret this set of Latitude and Longitude?

Tags: measurements, mapping

I have a house's coordinates that I know is in LA, Ventura, or Orange county, California and it says the latitude and longitude are

```
latitude    longitude
34144442    -118654084
```

These seem really big. How can I find the address this corresponds to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your coordinates are written in decimal degrees but with the decimal points omitted.

34.144442 -118.654084 corresponds to 34°08'40.0"N 118°39'14.7"W.

[Google maps](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/34%C2%B008'40.0%22N+118%C2%B039'14.7%22W/@34.1785346,-119.0523377,10z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d34.144442!4d-118.654084) shows this to be a location just outside LA.

Comment: Wow thanks! exactly what I was looking for